# UNIX : Meridian indicator (AM/AP) blank with specific LANG

Tags: bash, unix, date

I want to customise my prompt. Here is my problem :

```
root@server:~# PS1="[\@]\$" // should write [05:40 PM]
[05:40 ]$
```

Maybe this can be a lead ?

```
root@server:~# LANG=en_EN.UTF-8
root@server:~# date +%T%p
17:25:05PM
```

And now :

```
root@server:~# LANG=fr_FR.UTF-8
root@server:~# date +%T%p
17:25:15
root@server:~# date +%p

root@server:~#
```

Thanks a lot !

---

EDIT 1: That changes nothing for PS1 !

```
root@server:~# LANG=en_EN.UTF-8
root@server:~# PS1="[\@]\$"
[05:40 ]$
```

---

EDIT 2: That works fine, but I expect unwanted changes :

```
root@server:~# LC_ALL=C
root@server:~# PS1="[\@]\$"
[06:34 PM]$
```

but I see no differences in locales when I type `locale` before `LC_ALL=C` and after !

```
root@server:~# PS1="[\@] \$"
[06:44 ] $locale
LANG=fr_FR.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
[06:44 ] $env
// ...
LANG=fr_FR.UTF-8
// ...
```

Then :

```
[06:45 ] $LC_ALL=C
[06:45 PM]$locale
LANG=fr_FR.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
[06:46 PM] $env
// ...
LANG=fr_FR.UTF-8
// ...
```

What other variable does `LC_ALL`change ?! ...

Comment: Hmm seems to work in bash 4.2.10 on Linux Mint 12. How about giving `LC_ALL=C` a try?

Comment: Nice clue : `LC_ALL=C` update my PS1 to the correct value ! (`[06:14 PM]`). But does LC_ALL=C make others changes I don't want ? I mean ok, in my bashrc I put `LC_ALL=C` then `LANG=fr_FR.UTF-8`, but I expect others changes, did I ?

Comment: I think so, `LC_ALL` has precedence over `LANG`. Please see [this link](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xbd/envvar.html) for details about `LANG` & `LC_*`. I'm guessing you might avoid other changes and set only time i.e. `LC_TIME=C` (as you can see an example of French lang & German sort later in the page)

Comment: After test (thanks for your link) : see my EDIT 2 above.

Comment: Doesn't `locale` list `LC_ALL`? It should be blank before setting & set to `C` later. *But if* `locale` has not changed then I'm *guessing* you can take the leap of faith ;)

Comment: `LC_ALL` changes all `LC_*` values. This is what I get: before - `$ locale
LANG=en_IN
LANGUAGE=en_IN:en
LC_CTYPE="en_IN"
...
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_IN"
LC_ALL=`, after `$ export LC_ALL=C
$ locale
LANG=en_IN
LANGUAGE=en_IN:en
LC_CTYPE="C"
...
LC_IDENTIFICATION="C"
LC_ALL=C`. As you can see `LC_ALL` was blank prior to setting to `C`

Comment: Please look to the detail I just added. Nothing seems changed ... Where am I wrong ? :(

Comment: en_EN is a generic English locale. If you want US conventions such as AM/PM, use en_US (perhaps some others can be used, I'm not sure).

Using the C locale is discouraged in desktop environments, unless you want to deliberately limit your interoperability with non-ASCII world.

Comment: Hmm I'm not quite sure about that. As @n.m. has suggested that using `C` locale is discouraged. **If** you need this only for `PS1` then you can use a function to get the current time & set it

Comment: @n.m. : I'm in a server environment, but OK, I will not use `C` locale. @another.anon.coward yes, it's just for `PS1` so I will do that.

Comment: In a server environment it **is** OK and maybe even advisable to use C locale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need time to be displayed only for your command prompt then you could try to call a function which sets `PS1` using `trap`. This may not be the most ideal way to do it but you can be assured that you wont be messing with locale stuff by setting `LC_ALL`. You can do something on these lines:

```
$ function display_prompt(){ prompt_time=$(LC_ALL=C date +%r); PS1="[$prompt_time] $ "; }
$ trap display_prompt DEBUG
[11:25:45 PM] $
```

You can choose any format of `date` you want. You can add it in `~/.bashrc` file.
Hope this helps!

Comment: Agreed. This may be not the most ideal way to do, but I prefer not to change `LC_ALL`. Thanks ! Edit : no manual entry for trap .. ?!

Answer (score 0):

Well it makes sense if that locale doesn't have/use AM/PM notation.

Comment: @Ash_ It would seem that the only option is to set `LC_ALL`, although I find it curious that setting `LC_TIME` isn't enough

Comment: I add new content. See above.

Comment: @Ash_ Oh yeah, you will have to use `export PS1="[\$(LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 date +'%I:%m%p')]> "` or something similar if you want that in `PS1`, or you will have to put `export LANG` into your `.bashrc`

Comment: I wish like not to use others functions like date etc :/ I 'll try to find that particular locale.

Comment: @Ash_ Well, all English locales have PM/AM times. `en_US.UTF-8` is a good choice.